# Determining ESXi boot partition

Tags: vmware-esxi

What does boostate and updated field mean in boot.cfg? I am trying to figure out the way to determine the bootbank from which ESXi will boot. I was thinking of relying on bootstate = 0 but found that both bootbanks can have bootstate of 0.

Comment: May I ask why you're looking for this?

Answer (score 3):

The bootstate value determines whether the bootbank is usable.

A value of:
0 indicates a functioning bootbank,
1 indicates a recently upgraded bootbank,
2 indicates a defective bootbank and
3 indicates a bootbank has been voluntarily marked as bad/invalid for the purposes of rollback
-1 is an invalid boot.cfg

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/278895/how-is-the-altbootbank-partition-used-in-esxi) question the boot.cfg with the higher updated value is the primary bootbank.  I'm not certain on the use of boot state.